# Detect and delete gaps in time series

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have daily time series for different companies in my dataset and work with PostgreSQL. My goal is to exclude companies with too incomplete time series. Therefor I want to exclude all companies which have 3 or more consecutive missing values. Furthermore I want to exclude all companies which have more than 50% missing values between their first and final date in the dataset.

We can work with the following example data:

```
date             company    value
2012-01-01       A          5
2012-01-01       B          2
2012-01-02       A          NULL
2012-01-02       B          2
2012-01-02       C          4
2012-01-03       A          NULL
2012-01-03       B          NULL
2012-01-03       C          NULL
2012-01-04       A          NULL
2012-01-04       B          NULL
2012-01-04       C          NULL
2012-01-05       A          8
2012-01-05       B          9
2012-01-05       C          3
2012-01-06       A          8
2012-01-06       B          9
2012-01-06       C          NULL
```

So A has to be excluded because it has a gap of three consecutive missing values, and C because it has more than 50% missing values between its first and final date.

Combining other answers in this forum I made up the following code:

1. Add an autoincrement primary key to identify each row

   ```
   CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY company, date; 
   CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq; ALTER TABLE test ADD id INT UNIQUE; 
   ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('id_seq'); 
   UPDATE test SET id = NEXTVAL('id_seq');

   ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
   ```
2. Detect the gaps in the time series

   ```
   CREATE TABLE to_del AS WITH count3 AS 
   ( SELECT *, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY id 
              ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) 
     AS cnt FROM test) 
   SELECT company, id FROM count3 WHERE cnt >= 3;
   ```
3. Delete the gaps from mytable

   ```
   DELETE FROM mytable WHERE company in (SELECT DISTINCT company FROM to_del);
   ```

It seems to achieve to detect and delete gaps of 3 or more consecutive missing values from the time series. But this approach is very cumbersome. And I can't figure out how to additinoally exclude all companies with more than 50% missing values.

Can you think of a more effective solution than mine (I just learn to work with PostgreSQL), that also manages to exclude companies with more than 50% missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create only one query:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE company in (
  SELECT Company 
  FROM (
    SELECT Company, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY id 
               ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) As cnt,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company)
      / 
      COUNT(*) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company) As p50
  ) alias
  WHERE cnt >= 3 OR p50 > 0.5
)
```

A composite index on (company + value) columns can help to gain a maximum speed of this query.

---

EDIT

---

The above query doesn't work
I've corrected it slightly, here is a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9bfe/7

Two things have been changed:
- PARTITION BY company **ORDER BY date** instead of **ORDER BY id**
- explicit cast to numeric( because integer have been truncated to 0): 
OVER (PARTITION BY company)**::numeric**

```
  SELECT company, cnt, p50
  FROM (
    SELECT company, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY date 
               ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) As cnt,
      SUM(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company)::numeric
      / 
      COUNT(*) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY company) As p50
    FROM mytable
  ) alias
--  WHERE cnt >= 3 OR p50 > 0.5
```

and now the delete query should work:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE company in (
      SELECT company
      FROM (
        SELECT company, 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY date 
                   ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) As cnt,
          SUM(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY company)::numeric
          / 
          COUNT(*) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY company) As p50
        FROM mytable
      ) alias
    WHERE cnt >= 3 OR p50 > 0.5
)
```

Comment: Thank you, using only one query looks very elegant to me. So I try to follow your approach, but somehow it's not quite working yet. So far it's excluding the rows with missing values. What I need is to exclude all firms entirely from the dataset that satisfy one of the two criteria. @kordirko

Comment: I've modified my answer, the previous query was wrong.

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly. Thank you for your answer and also for the demo to help me understand how it works! @kordirko

Answer (score 1):

For the 50% criteria, you could select all the companies for which the number of distinct dates in lower than half the number of days between the min and max dates.

I have not tested this but it should give you an idea. I used a CTE to make it easier to read.

```
WITH MinMax AS 
(
    SELECT Company, DATE_PART('day', AGE(MIN(Date), MAX(Date))) AS calendar_days, COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS days FROM table
     GROUP By Company
)
SELECT Company FROM MinMax
 WHERE (calendars_days / 2) > days
```